# How to stack our data in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I want to stack my data based on two-column as follows:

```html
df1<-read.table(text="A B C Group Class D E F
2 2 3 N1 NA 6 6 7
1 2 3 M2 N2 10 2 9
3 1 3 N2 M2 5 6 10
1 2 3 M1 NA 6 3 3
2 1 1 N2 M2 8 10 5
2 1 1 M1 N1 1 7 4
1 2 3 N1 M1 2 10 1
",header=TRUE)
```

Two main columns are Group and Class. First I want to filter M1 and M2 from Group then I want to get M1 and M2 from class. I want to add these data at the end of the data that get from Group and then I rename data to M1 and M2.

Here would be the outcome

```html
Outcome<-read.table(text="A B C Group Class D E F
1 2 3 M2 N2 10 2 9
1 2 3 M1 NA 6 3 3
2 1 1 M1 N1 1 7 4
3 1 3 M2 M2 5 6 10
2 1 1 M2 M2 8 10 5
1 2 3 M1 M1 2 10 1

",header=TRUE)
```

Can we do it in R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a step by step code exampling doing what you described in `tidyverse`.

```
library(tidyverse)

# Filter the Group column by M1, M2
df2 <- df1 %>%
  filter(Group %in% c("M1", "M2"))

# Filter the Class column by M1, M2, and then replace N with M in the Group column
df3 <- df1 %>%
  filter(Class %in% c("M1", "M2")) %>%
  mutate(Group = recode(Group, N1 = "M1", N2 = "M2"))

# Combine the datasets
df4 <- bind_rows(df2, df3)
```